# Run function on event

Tags: ajax, jquery

im trying to run javascript function when other funcion will stop.
For example: `User change something in form and ajax has been sent in background. When ajax request is done i want to run function.`

How can i do that ?

Or maybe there is a global trigger for ajax requests ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you are using jQuery, so you can use the "complete" or "success" settings to call code/function. Check the docs.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    success: function(){
    // call another function
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achive that thanks to ajax asynchronous request and handler. If you, for example, call via ajax a page that do a particular function and then return, you can run your js.

Take a look at this:  [http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/](http://JQuery)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a handler for the ajax request which gets called when you get response for the request. You can check the examples at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a specific function for a specific AJAX call, simply call it as part of the `success` or `complete` callbacks on that AJAX call. If, however, you want to call the same function whenever **any** AJAX request is finished, take a look at the [`.ajaxSuccess()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) or [`.ajaxComplete()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) methods in the jQuery API.